typescript how to flatten nested generic type into parent generic type
my goal is, for a given type that contains Nested generic
type Example = { a: string, b: string, n: Nested<{ n1: 'n1-val', n2: 'n2-val' }> }

flat Nested into parent type by implementing FlatNested:
type t1 = FlatNested<Example>
//   ^? goal: {a: string;b: string;n1: "n1-val" ;n2: "n2-val";}

current progress
type Nested<T> = T &
{ _: string } // this just so Nested<T> wont be equal to T

type Example = { a: string, b: string, n: Nested<{ n1: 'n1-val', n2: 'n2-val' }> }

type FlatNested<T> = { [K in keyof T as T[K] extends Nested<infer N> ? keyof N : K]: T[K] extends Nested<infer N> ? T[K][keyof N] : T[K] };

type t1 = FlatNested<Example>
//   ^? type t1 = {a: string;b: string;n1: "n1-val" | "n2-val";n2: "n1-val" | "n2-val";}
//   ^? goal: {a: string;b: string;n1: "n1-val" ;n2: "n2-val";}

I'm quite close but not there yet, I'm unable to separate the values for the keys in the nested type. no matter what i try, i end up with the union of all the values, and not the one that is matching the current renamed mapped type(what comes after as).
simple Playground
actual usecase

Does this approach meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz amazing. you are typescript artist! could you please explain the trick of mapping the type temporary to function and inferring from it?

You can't do this with pure key remapping because each key K can only result in a single property type in the output, even if you map K to a union of keys. Essentially you don't get a new "loop" when you map a single key to multiple.
Instead, I'd be inclined to convert each property of T to some piece we intersect to form the whole.
We want FlatNested<{ a: string, b: string, n: Nested<{ n1: 'n1-val', n2: 'n2-val' }> }> to become something like {a: string} & {b: string} & {n1: 'n1-val', n2: 'n2-val'}.  Then that intersection can be flattened into the type you're looking for.
To that end, I will do something like the technique shown in Transform union type to intersection type, where we move the intended piece to intersect into a contravariant type position (see Difference between Variance, Covariance, Contravariance, Bivariance and Invariance in TypeScript) and infer from that to get the intersection:
type FlatNested<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: (x: T[K] extends Nested<infer N> ? N : Pick<T, K>) => void
} extends { [k: string]: (x: infer I) => void } ? { [K in keyof I]: I[K] } : never

For each property T[K], if it is a Nested<infer N>, then the piece we want to intersect is N.  Otherwise we want to intersect Pick<T, K>, which is just the current property. So if K is "a" and T[K] is string, then we want to use {a: string}, which is Pick<T, "a">.
This gets mapped to a contravariant type position (the parameter for a function) and then we infer a single function parameter type from it, which gives us the intersection as I.
And finally we flatten it with a simple identity mapped type (see How can I see the full expanded contract of a Typescript type?).

Let's try it out:
type T1 = FlatNested<Example>
/* type T1 = {
    a: string;
    b: string;
    n1: 'n1-val';
    n2: 'n2-val';
} */

Looks good.
Playground link to code

awesome solution @jcalz. one last thing, how would you make it work recursively? (for Nested that may contain other Nested)

That's a followup question an therefore out of scope here. You could try replacing ? N :  with ? FlatNested<N> : to make it recursive and see what happens. If it works for you, great. If not, and you care about the answer, you should open another question post for it.
